# Series of sum of random variables in tail $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I seem to have misunderstood something fundamental about $\sigma$-tail algebras, as I cannot resolve the following problem:

Given a series of real random variables $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Then

$X^*=\displaystyle \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is in the $\sigma$-tail algebra $\mathcal{T}((X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}})$

I can show this using the following arguments:

**First step:** $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is $\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$ measurable, since $X_i$ is $\sigma(X_i)$ measurable for all $i=1,...,n$ and the fact that the sum of measurable maps (and multiplying by a constant) is again measurable, particularly measurable in the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_1,...,X_n$, being $\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$.

**Second step:** It follows that $\displaystyle \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is $\sigma((X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}})$ measurable, because the limit is measurable for measurable maps.

**Third step:** Since $\displaystyle \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i= \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=k}^n X_i$
 it follows that $X^*$ is $\sigma(X_n,\ n\ge k)$ measurable for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ which means that $X^*$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{T}((X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}})$

This is correct so far, right?

Now lets look at $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ for *i.i.d* random variables $X_i$. Is $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n$ measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{T}((S_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}})$?

Here comes my fallacy: I would just argue that, since $\sigma((X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}})=\sigma(X_1)$, because $X_i$ are i.i.d, and again by the argument that the sum and limit of measurable functions are again measurable, we immediately have that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n$ is $\mathcal{T}((S_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}})$ measurable.

However, someone told me this is not correct. Where is my mistake?

Comment: I wouldn't agree that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is $\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ measurable. This random variable would not be measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by finitely many of the $X_i$.

Comment: @Math1000 Sorry, that was clearly a mistake, I will edit.

Comment: Your mistake is in thinking $\sigma(X_1)=\sigma((X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N})$. The former has events involving $X_1$ alone, the latter has events involving the other $X_n$ as well.  The event thst $X_2>0$ is not in $\sigma(X_1)$, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is far from truth that if $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. then $\sigma (X,Y)=\sigma (X)$. I fact these two sigma algebras cannot be equal unless $Y$ is a constant! Proof: if this is true then $Y$ is independent of $X$ and also measurable w.r.t. $\sigma (X)$ which implies that $Y$ is independent of itself, hence a constant almost surely.

Comment: But we have $\sigma(X,Y):=\sigma(\sigma(X)\cup\sigma(Y))$ and if $X=Y$ how is this different from just $\sigma(X)$? Isn't $\sigma(X):=X^{-1}(\mathcal{A})$ for $\mathcal{A}$ a $\sigma$ algebra in the target space, constituting the same sets as $\sigma(Y)$?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta I.i.d. does  not mean that the random variables are equal. In  fact two i.i.d random variable are never equal (unless they are constants).  $X$ and $Y$ having same distribution is VERY VERY different from $X=Y$.

Comment: By $X=Y$ I meant in distribution. Still, I don't see from the definition why they would generate different $\sigma$-algebras. I will post another question I think. Your answer led me to the root of my misunderstanding, thanks. Nevertheless, it kind of freaks me out how I have overlooked something like this.

Comment: But the reasoning for the first example is correct, right?